# Is there any way to not redraw/invalidate a view but to scaleX and scaleY with layout fitting the new scaled Width&Height?

Tags: android, view, scaling

I have a `customView`, `onDraw` there is some paths creating a drawing `100px * 100px` size.
Due to some reason, the drawing is too complicated with different size `LinearGradient` for different `paints`. For simplicity, I draw a arrow image for you to get the idea as an example.

In my `customView`, it has the following properties:

1. clickable, if clicked the colored drawing, it will be invisible. (here the layout dimension is important to be exact or nearly exact with no large margin)
2. originally it is 50% size with `setPivot(0,0)` and located at coordinates (a1,b1).
3. 2 seconds later, it will finally be 100% size with `setPivot(0,0)` and located at coordinates (a2,b2).

I know using animation can do 2 and 3, however I have no idea how to automatically modify the layout dimension (i.e. clickable region) for the animator for my `customView`.

I know redrawing a view spend much memory. People say scaling and translation only some memory and redraw will not be activate.
Hence, I try to use valueAnimator and `setDuration` to be 2 second, and `ofInt(60)` for 60fps.
I added an AnimatorUpdateListener and update the expected current scaling ratio `(0.5f+(1-0.5f)*time_elapsed/2000` and also use

```
view.setScaleX(current_scaling_ratio);
view.setScaleY(current_scaling_ratio);
```

However, I think there is problem to set an exact clickable region by using setScaleX or setScaleY.
Please see the following bmp image I conclude.

`setScale` will do only after `layout(l,t,r,b)` becomes effective and then used this new layout dimension to `setScale`, no matter the order of the codes you enter.

[image]

Then,
I try to inspect the codes behind setScaleX and want to see why it can scale a view/drawing without redraw it. However, I found the following:

```
    public void setScaleX(float scaleX) {
        if (scaleX != getScaleX()) {
            scaleX = sanitizeFloatPropertyValue(scaleX, "scaleX");
            invalidateViewProperty(true, false);
            mRenderNode.setScaleX(scaleX);
            invalidateViewProperty(false, true);

            invalidateParentIfNeededAndWasQuickRejected();
            notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChangedIfNeeded();
        }
    }
```

```
void invalidateViewProperty(boolean invalidateParent, boolean forceRedraw) {
        if (!isHardwareAccelerated()
                || !mRenderNode.isValid()
                || (mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_DRAW_ANIMATION) != 0) {
            if (invalidateParent) {
                invalidateParentCaches();
            }
            if (forceRedraw) {
                mPrivateFlags |= PFLAG_DRAWN; // force another invalidation with the new orientation
            }
            invalidate(false);
        } else {
            damageInParent();
        }
    }
```

```
    protected void invalidateParentCaches() {
        if (mParent instanceof View) {
            ((View) mParent).mPrivateFlags |= PFLAG_INVALIDATED;
        }
    }
```

However, I try to use `parentView.mPrivateFlags |= PFLAG_INVALIDATED;` The Android Studio gives me a red color on `mPrivateFlags`. It is a public parameter but I don't know why cannot refer to it. Now I can't continue. I just want to make a smooth view which is originally scaled down and within 2 seconds, it keep moving linearly and scaling up back to original size gradually. Also the clickable region should be small and exact enough to fit the view along the flying path so when I need to determine if the point clicked is ARGB transparent or not to conclude if it is a effective click.